# Streamlit Ag-Grid checkbox selection for grouped table

Tags: checkbox, ag-grid, streamlit, grouped-table

I am trying to implement checkbox selection in the grouped Ag-Grid table from a pre-determined dataframe which I read from a csv file (if it is connected to some other Ag-Grid that you have before in a code where you already have a checkbox option enabled it works/it is not a problem).

So when I have have a drop down ‘arrow/menu’ for each grouped item there I would like to have also a checkbox. Is that even possible?

Thank you for your help!

Best regards,
Jaša

Answer (score 0):

You can add checkboxes by including `"checkboxSelection": True` in the `columnDefs` section of `gridOptions` ([example](https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid-examples/blob/3bb054f037e0fa5d20b368ab36a0839c0a84e758/nested_grids.py)).